# how to override Reviews Module

Tags: magento2, module, extend

I'm working on Custom module in which I need to override Magento's reviews Module. I want to add some extra fields in Magento's Review Form. I created Preferences in 
adminhtml/di.xml Now whenever I add my custom fields code, all the other fields get removed.

```
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    \Magento\Review\Helper\Data $reviewData,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_reviewData = $reviewData;
    $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare add review form
 *
 * @return void
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('add_review_form', ['legend' => __('Review Details')]);

    $fieldset->addField('product_name', 'note', ['label' => __('Product'), 'text' => 'product_name']);

    // $fieldset->addField(
    //     'detailed-rating',
    //     'note',
    //     [
    //         'label' => __('Product Rating'),
    //         'required' => true,
    //         'text' => '<div id="rating_detail">' . $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    //             \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Rating\Detailed::class
    //         )->toHtml() . '</div>'
    //     ]
    // );

    // $fieldset->addField(
    //     'status_id',
    //     'select',
    //     [
    //         'label' => __('Status'),
    //         'required' => true,
    //         'name' => 'status_id',
    //         'values' => $this->_reviewData->getReviewStatusesOptionArray()
    //     ]
    // );

    // /**
    //  * Check is single store mode
    //  */
    // if (!$this->_storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    //     $field = $fieldset->addField(
    //         'select_stores',
    //         'multiselect',
    //         [
    //             'label' => __('Visibility'),
    //             'required' => true,
    //             'name' => 'select_stores[]',
    //             'values' => $this->_systemStore->getStoreValuesForForm()
    //         ]
    //     );
    //     $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    //         \Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element::class
    //     );
    //     $field->setRenderer($renderer);
    // }

    // $fieldset->addField(
    //     'nickname',
    //     'text',
    //     [
    //         'name' => 'nickname',
    //         'title' => __('Nickname'),
    //         'label' => __('Nickname'),
    //         'maxlength' => '50',
    //         'required' => true
    //     ]
    // );

    // $fieldset->addField(
    //     'title',
    //     'text',
    //     [
    //         'name' => 'title',
    //         'title' => __('Summary of Review'),
    //         'label' => __('Summary of Review'),
    //         'maxlength' => '255',
    //         'required' => true
    //     ]
    // );

    // $fieldset->addField(
    //     'detail',
    //     'textarea',
    //     [
    //         'name' => 'detail',
    //         'title' => __('Review'),
    //         'label' => __('Review'),
    //         'required' => true
    //     ]
    // );

     $fieldset->addFieldset(
        'review_comment',
        ['legend' => __('Review Comment'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'title_comment',
        'text',
        ['label' => __('Title'), 'required' => false, 'name' => 'comment-title']
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'comment',
        'textarea',
        ['label' => __('Comment'), 'required' => false, 'name' => 'comment']
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'send_customer',
        'checkbox',
        ['label' => __('Send this Comment to customer'), 'required' => false, 'name' => 'show_to_customer']
    );


    $fieldset->addField('product_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'product_id']);

    /*$gridFieldset = $form->addFieldset('add_review_grid', array('legend' => __('Please select a product')));
      $gridFieldset->addField('products_grid', 'note', array(
      'text' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid::class)->toHtml(),
      ));*/

    $form->setMethod('post');
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $form->setId('edit_form');
    $form->setAction($this->getUrl('review/product/post'));

    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

also, whenever I add my fields using this method $fieldset->addField it gives an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use plugin for that.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Add\Form">
       <plugin name="review_add_form_custom" type="QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Plugin\Add\Form" />
   </type>
</config>
```

Review Add Form

Now Create **Form.php** file in following directory
**app\code\QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Plugin\Adminhtml\Add**

```
namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Plugin\Adminhtml\Add;

  class Form extends \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Add\Form
  {
   public function beforeSetForm(\Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Add\Form $object, $form) {

       $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
           'review_cusom',
           ['legend' => __('Review Custom Field'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
       );

       $fieldset->addField(
           'test',
           'text',
           ['label' => __('Test'), 'required' => false, 'name' => 'test']
       );


       return [$form];
   }
}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-add-extra-fields-in-magento-2-core-review-module-form/)

Comment: Our pleasure. Happy codding!

Answer (score 0):

If You need to override Magento's reviews Module. I want to add some extra fields in Magento's Review Form.

**MagentoFolder/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml**

Override the Following in your custom Module Layout File.

https://prnt.sc/kffwcc

Comment: This frontend form. I want to override backend form.

Answer (score 0):

```
   *$fieldset->addFieldset(*
      'review_comment',
       ['legend' => __('Review Comment'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
   );
```

fieldset doesn't have addFieldset() method.So change above code snippet to:

```
   $fieldset->addField(
      'review_comment',
       ['legend' => __('Review Comment'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
   );
```

Comment: I am still confused. Can you plz add one field using above snippet?

Comment: If you take a look at your posted source code, you will find you are doing like: $fieldset->addFieldset(...). I think this is incorrect.